# why doesn't the following code show the Red channel of an image?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat src = imread("image.png", 1);
    namedWindow("src", 1); 
    imshow("src", src);

    vector<Mat> rgbChannels(3);
    split(src, rgbChannels);

    namedWindow("R", 1); 
    imshow("R", rgbChannels[2]);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

.

I was expecting something like the following:

[image]

why doesn't the above code show the Red channel? why does it show a grayscale image?

if the image is split into 3 channels, each matrix should show one of the colors of r, g, and b. isn't that so?

Comment: Most likely this but I don't want to close as a dupe since the language is different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554125/python-want-to-display-red-channel-only-in-opencv

Comment: You can tell it is the Red channel because reddish areas in the original area are light in the greyscale version, whereas blueish areas in the original image are dark in the greyscale version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct; however, OpenCV is showing the channel as grayscale. `Mat` does not keep the information about "where" the data came from. In other words, it does not know it was a red channel, so when you call `imshow`, it displays it as a single-channel image.

What you can do is build up an empty image with 2 zero'd channels and the one you want to visualize.

Comment: why do we need to split then? why not just copy the image thrice and zero two channels we don't want to see?

Comment: @anonymous: No one said you need `split` -- you can build the "colorized" image in any way you want! :-)