# TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class ‘bool’>

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

I would like to split images using Open CV then feed to the by PyTorch model to count object in each image. I am getting the following error message when running the code: TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class ‘bool’>

```
import os

import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms, utils
#from torchvision.transforms import Grayscalei
import pandas as pd
import pdb
import cv2

class CellsDataset(Dataset):
    # a very simple dataset

    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None, return_filenames=False):
        self.root = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.return_filenames = return_filenames
        self.files = [os.path.join(self.root,filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.root)]
        self.files = [path for path in self.files
                      if os.path.isfile(path) and os.path.splitext(path)[1]=='.png']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = self.files[idx]
        sample = Image.open(path)        

        sample = cv2.imread(path)
        b,g,r=cv2.split(sample)
        sample=cv2.imwrite('sample.png', g)


        #transform3 = Grayscale(num_output_channels=3)
        #sample = transform3(sample) # convert to a 3 channel grayscale, as it needs to be 3 channel.
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        if self.return_filenames:
            return sample, path
        else:
            return sample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `sample` is reassigned to what `cv2.imwrite` returns in this line:

```
sample=cv2.imwrite('sample.png', g)
```

That replaces your ndarray with something else.

Try replacing that line with simply `cv2.imwrite('sample.png', g)` without assigning the value of the evaluated expression to `sample`.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help. That code runs okay now without any error. If i print an image cv2.imshow('sample',2) - It's showing in gray scale and not in green any idea please?

Comment: The snippet you sent wouldn't work at all since 'sample' is a string. But probably you're sending a 1-channel image (ndarray) to imshow, and cv2 will just show it as a luminosity channel, regardless if you originally got the 1-channel image by splitting the channels in a rgb image.

Comment: Thanks again. Would you be able to tell me what i need to do in order to transform the image to show red or green channel please? Many Thanks! The reason for the transform to be able to count the number of cell in microscopy image based on green and red cells.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do color filtering. It's not too complicated with cv2 to do something more sophisticated than just picking a channel. See for example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-color-with-opencv/

Though it's also possible to just use a naïve threshold on a channel as a mask: `mask = g > 128`. 

For both masks: `masked_sample = cv2.bitwise_and(sample, sample, mask)`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. It is really appreciated.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554125/python-want-to-display-red-channel-only-in-opencv/44554763

Comment: @AA2018-2020 `cv2.imwrite` returns a `bool` to denote whether the image was successfully written to disk.  Keep this in mind when you're using `cv2.imwrite` in the future.